# Thresholding an image taken using camera in javaCV

Tags: java, image-processing, javacv

Thresholding image in JavaCV

I followed several steps to threshold an image which was taken using a camera.  But half of the image becomes black.  I tried several types of thresholding algorithms non of them work.
the code i used for thresholding is given below,

```
cvCvtColor(src, colorDst, CV_GRAY2BGR);
cvThreshold(colorDst, threshold, 155, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
//cvThreshold(colorDst, threshold, 155, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU); // code didnt work in javaCV
```

Is there any algorithms which would threshold properly the whole image which was taken using a camera?

Original Image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c6HL.jpg

Thresholded Image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qprdZ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Threshold = 155 is too high for this image - right side is darker and therefore becomes black.
The optimal value is about 120 (you can find it out using for example GIMP Color Picker).

If you want the threshold to be computed automatically, use THRESH_OTSU or THRESH_TRIANGLE. Don't use BGR image, this function works properly only for grayscale images.

If you threshold this image as a grayscale one using Triangle algorithm it will yield threshold = 117 and image will be thresholded properly (code for OpenCV-3.0b):

```
Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread("res/test.jpg", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat dst = new Mat();
double threshold = Imgproc.threshold(src, dst, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_TRIANGLE);
Imgcodecs.imwrite("res/out.jpg", dst);
System.out.println(threshold); // 117
```

[image: src.jpg]
[image: out.jpg]